# How to define a type with defined properties and an index "fallback" in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Use case: I am receiving data from a remote API. The data is dynamically generated and sometimes changing. I know the type I will receive is an array of objects, each containing at minimum properties called "value" and "description"

```js
interface Item {
  value: string
  description: string
}
type Response = Item[]
```

However, the response also will contain other, unknown data. I will write a function to normalize this data by pruning all properties that do not match one of the following criteria:

1. property index is "value"
2. property index is "description"
3. property *value* is of type `Item[]` (property indexes are not know at my app's compile time)

```js
interface IncomingItem {
  value: string
  description: string
  [index:string]: unknown
}

interface NormalizedItem {
  value: string
  description: string
  [index:string]: NormalizedItem[]

declare const normalizeItem : (i:IncomingItem) => OutgoingItem
declare const items: IncomingItem[]
const normalizeItems = items.map(normalizeItem) //NormalizedItem[]
```

I can't seem to find a way to do this. I tried the above types but you can't have an index type that is not the type of the defined properties.

Then I tried this, which is a valid type, but you cannot assign data to this type:

```
type NormalizedType = {
  value:string
  description:string
} & {[index:string]:NormalizedType[]}

declare const getOnlyIncomingTypeArrays : (i:IncomingType) => {[index:string]:IncomingType[]}

const normalize = (i:IncomingType):NormalizedType => ({
  value: i.value,
  description: i.description,
  ...normalize(getOnlyIncomingTypeArrays(i)),
})
```

but you cannot assign to `NormalizedType` without getting a TS error.

Comment: Alternatively I can define such a type, put `@ts-ignore` above it, but every time I *use* a function that returns that type, the type is tracked correctly!